# Binary search of a Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, binary-search

> Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an m x n
>   matrix.
>
> This matrix has the following properties:
>
> -Integers in each row are sorted from left to right. 
> -The first integer
>   of each row is greater than or equal to the last integer of the
>   previous row. 
> Example:
>
> Consider the following matrix:
>
> [
>     [1,   3,  5,  7],
>     
> [10, 11, 16, 20],
>    [23, 30, 34, 50] 
> ] 
> Given
>   target = 3, return 1 ( 1 corresponds to true )
>
> Return 0 / 1 ( 0 if the element is not present, 1 if the element is
>   present ) for this problem

My solution works on NetBeans but fails on the website. Any help will be appreciated.
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/matrix-search/

```
public class Solution {

    public int searchMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a, int b) {
        int r = a.size();
        int c = a.get(0).size();

        int start = 0;
        int end = r - 1;
        // default value is last row for edge case
        int biRow = r -1; // row to search column

        //binary search 1st value of rows
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (b == a.get(mid).get(0)) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (a.get(mid).get(0) < b && b < a.get(end).get(0)) {
                if (mid + 1 >= end) {
                    biRow = mid;
                    break;
                }
            } if (b < a.get(mid).get(0)) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        //binary search column of biRow
        start = 0;
        end = c-1;
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (b == a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b < a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just treat the NxM matrix as an array of N*M items, with the obvious ordering, and apply ordinary binary search on that with the coordinate transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the shared program seems to have a logical error.

When updating the end value in the first while loop, if the end value is equal to start, biRow can not be updated.

It worked well when I updated the code like below.

```
public class Solution {
    public int searchMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a, int b) {
        int r = a.size();
        int c = a.get(0).size();
        int start = 0;
        int end = r - 1;
        // default value is last row for edge case
        int biRow = r -1; // row to search column

        //binary search 1st value of rows
        int mid = 0;
        while (start <= end) {
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if ( b >= a.get(mid).get(0) && b <= a.get(mid).get(c-1)) {
                break;
            }
            if (b < a.get(mid).get(0)) {
                end = mid-1;
            } else {
                start = mid+1;
            }
       }

        biRow = mid;

        //binary search column of biRow
        start = 0;
        end = c-1;
        while (start <= end) {
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (b == a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b < a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the first thing you **MUST NOT** do is that, you cannot physically concat the matrix into a 1D vector, as this is `O(N*M)` which is linear and not what we want.

```cs
// Easy but TLE code
int Solution::searchMatrix(vector<vector<int> > &A, int B) {
    vector<int> v;
    for(auto a : A) v.insert(v.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
    return binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), B);
}
```

So the point is, you have to do binary search directly on the matrix, and that is pretty much the same (except you have to write binary search your own now).

As you did not really access all of the elements, this is `O(lg (N*M))`

```cs
// Less Easy but AC code
int Solution::searchMatrix(vector<vector<int> > &A, int B) {
    int m = A.size(), n = A[0].size(), lo = 0, hi = m*n-1, mi, row, col;
    while(lo <= hi){
        mi = lo + ((hi-lo) >> 1);
        row = mi / n;
        col = mi % n;
        if(A[row][col] == B) return 1;
        else if(A[row][col] > B) hi = mi - 1;
        else lo = mi + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is logical error in your row search loop. I made a correction and I also added the boundary conditions.Time complexity of this algorithm is O(logN).

```
public class Solution {
    public int searchMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a, int b) {
        int r = a.size();
        int c = a.get(0).size();

        // return 0 if b is less than 1st element or greater than last element
        if (b < a.get(0).get(0) || b > a.get(r - 1).get(c - 1))
            return 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = r - 1;
        // default value is last row for edge case
        int biRow = r - 1; // row to search column

        // binary search 1st value of rows
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (b == a.get(mid).get(0)) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (b >= a.get(mid).get(0) && b <= a.get(mid).get(c - 1)) {
                {
                    biRow = mid;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (b < a.get(mid).get(0)) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        // binary search column of biRow
        start = 0;
        end = c - 1;
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            if (b == a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b < a.get(biRow).get(mid)) {
                end = mid - 1;
            } else {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows and columns are sorted, a binary search will be proper as you said. This is a binary search(on a matrix) implementation in Ruby

```
def binary_search_on_matrix(matrix,target)
  row_size = matrix.size
  column_size = matrix[0].size
  left_index = 0
  right_index = (row_size * column_size) - 1  
  while (left_index <= right_index)  
    mid_point = left_index + ((right_index - left_index) / 2)
    row = mid_point / column_size
    col = mid_point % column_size
    value = matrix[row][col] 
    if (value == target)
      return true
    elsif (value > target)
      right_index = mid_point - 1
    else
      left_index = mid_point + 1
    end
 end
  return false
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can first convert your 2D array into 1D array and perform binary search operation. You can refer the code given below:

```
void search(int a[][10],int search,int m,int n)
{
    int arr[100],i=0,j=0,k=-1;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        arr[++k] = a[i][j];

    int first = 0 , last = k-1 , middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last)
    {
        if(arr[middle] < search)
        {
            first = middle + 1;

        }
        else if(arr[middle] == search)
        {
            printf("\n Element found at position:( %d , %d")",(middle/n)+1,(middle%n)+1);
            printf(" \n Row : %d",(middle/n)+1);
            printf("\n column : %d",(middle%n)+1);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
             last = middle - 1;
        }
        middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    if(first > last)
    {
        printf("\n Element not found! ");
    }
}
```

This function prints the row and column of element to be searched if it exists.You can modify this code, if You want the function to return a value depending on the search operation.

Comment: What about the complexity for converting 2D array into 1D array?

Comment: There are at least two major problems with this code. First, how can you be sure that everything will fit in array of size 100? Second, completely unnecessary copying of the whole matrix.